# unexpected result using regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, scripting

I made a trying to make regex expression that will validate a number that is in the range of -100 to 100.
the regex expression I made is ^[-+]?([0-9][0-9]?|100)$.
I am looking for a pattern in a string not just an integer by itself.

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="input2.txt"

while read -r line; do
mapfile -t d <<< "$line"

for i in "${d[@]}"; do
  if [[ "$i" =~ ^[-+]?([0-9][0-9]?|100)$ ]]; then
  echo "$i"
  fi
 done
done < "$a"
```

this is my input file:

```
add $s1 $s2 $s3
sub $t0 
sub $t1 $t0 
addi $t1 $t0 75
lw $s1 -23($s2)
```

the actual result is nothing.

the expected result:

```
75  -23($s2)
```

Comment: Your edit changed the question fundamentally and invalidated the answer that was given based on the first revision – please don't do that. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

`[...]` denotes a set of characters, where the dash can be used to specify a character range. For instance, `[4-6u-z]` in a regexp means one of the  characters 4,5,6,u,v,w,x,z. Your expression `[1-200]` simply matches the characters (digits) 0, 1 and 2.

In your case, I would therefore proceed in two steps: First, extract from your string the initial numeric parts, and then use arithmetic comparision on the result. For example (not tested!):

```
if [[ $i =~ ^-?[0-9]+ ]]
then
  intval=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
  if (( intval >= -200 && intval <= 1000 ))
  then
    ....
```

See the bash man page for an explanation of the *BASH_REMATCH* array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#first store your file in an array so that we could pass thru the words
word_array=( $(<filename) )
for i in "${word_array[@]}"
do 
if [[ $i =~ ^([[:blank:]]{0,1}-?[0-9]+)([^[:digit:]]?[^[:blank:]]*)$ ]]
#above line looks for the pattern while separating the number and an optional string 
#that may follow like ($s2) using '()' so that we could access each part using BASH_REMATCH later.
then 
#now we have only the number which could be checked to fall within a range
[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -ge -100 ] && [ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -le 100 ] && echo "$i"
fi
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
75
-23($s2)
```

<sub>**Note** : The pattern might need a bit more testing, but you could imbibe the idea.</sub>